# Angular 6 singleton service always resetting after APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to store some information in a object to be used across all components and this needs to be the first thing done in the app, so i'm trying to use APP_INITIALIZER to set the object in a singleton service to be available later in the components.

```
// app.module.ts
import { DataService } from './data.service';

providers: [DataService, { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp1, deps: [DataService], multi: true }],

export function initializeApp1(appInitService: DataService) {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return appInitService.Init();
  }
}

// data.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService { 
  public object = {
    "test1": "",
    "test2": ""
  };
  public getObj() {
    return this.object;
  }
  Init() {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
     // Requet some data from server
      this.getData().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.object = data;
        // Object set correctly
        resolve();
      });
    });
  }
}

// navbar.component.ts
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // This always return the object with empty properties
    var x = this.dataService.getObj();
  }
```

I think probably the service is being created twice or something like that, but i can't find or understand why.

Comment: I've done something similar before ([with this library I wrote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-config-loader)) and I haven't seen where it reset the objects but sometimes the `this.object` isn't yet set when asked for. So I had to use, in some cases, an observable.

Comment: Especially where you're starting the `this.object` object off with some empty values, it's possible that your values are not loaded when they're being asked for. It doesn't always happen, but using a subject in addition helped me. That way if the values didn't come back as expected I could wait for the `Subject.next` to be emitted.